# Oracle behavior with nvarchar2 and varchar2, behaves the same. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Here is my experiment with Oracle

```
create table xxx (a varchar2(10), b nvarchar2(20))
insert into xxx values(N'严並', N'严 並 丧')
insert into xxx values('严並', '严 並 丧')
select * from xxx
```

Returns

```
a       b
严並   严 並 丧
严並    严 並 丧
```

Although it does say that value is too large for my column `a` when I try to insert '並丧並並', it is still inserts smaller value.

In Sql Server the result is quite different. In Sql Server you must use `N` prefix

```
a       b
??   严 並 丧
??    ? ? ?
```

Does it mean that prefix `N` is not required in Oracle or it depends on the character set setting?
And, does it mean that Oracle, basically still finds the way how to store "large" characters in the field that generally not designed for it?

Thank you

Comment: `NVARCHAR` is only needed if your default characterset is not a multi-byte characterset. If you create your database with e.g. UTF-8 as the default character set, there is essentially no difference between `varchar` and `nvarchar`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - There could be a difference in number of bytes occupied between the same string as varchar and nvarchar.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: you are right because `nvarchar` usually uses a multi-byte encoding with a fixed number of bytes (I think the default is UTF-16), but for the content that can be stored there is essentially no difference

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff So, I can insert into `varchar2` without using `N` prefix because my language `AL16UTF16` or because Oracle explicitly runs conversion. I know that `TO_NCHAR` is run time and `N'string'` is compile time conversion. What if the database I work against is some, I know nothing about. Would it be safe just to mark all strings with 'N'?

Answer (score 0):

Your column "a" has a limitation of length.
You can execute sql below to check it:

```
select lengthb('並丧並並') from dual;  --12
```

Different results on different OS and mine is 12.

Comment: I know about size limitation. Your answer doesn't provide an answer to "why" I can store it in Varchar2. Nor it provides answer about prefix `N`.